# I have a text file and I need to delete the first blank line and then all the text after the 2nd blank line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm using bash and I have a file that is in 3 parts of text.  The first part, then a blank line, then the 2nd part then another blank line, then the file 3 part of text.  I need to output this to a new file that contains only the first 2 parts without the blank line in between.  I've been playing with sed and awk, but can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most simply with awk:

```
awk -v RS= 'NR <= 2' filename
```

With an empty record separator `RS`, awk splits the file into records at empty lines. With the selection `NR <= 2`, only the first two are printed (delimited by the default output record separator, which is a newline).

If the file is very large, it might be prudent to amend this to

```
awk -v RS= '1; NR == 2 { exit }' filename
```

This stops processing the file after the second record and prints all until then.

**Addendum:** Obligatory crazy sed solution (not recommended for use, written for fun):

```
sed -n '/^$/ { x; /./q; H; d; }; p' filename
```